# Удалить пары повторяющихся соседних элементов массива(js)

Tags: javascript, массивы

Удалить пары повторяющихся соседних элементов массива(js)

исходный массив `arr = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 32, 22, 22, 41, 50, 50];`

ожидаемый массив `arr = [10, 32, 41];`

Comment: супер, задание понятно, и в чем вопрос?

Comment: Привет) Не знаю как удалять именно пары, т.е если подряд 4 элемента - удалить их все, а если 5 - то  один элемент оставить

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм простой:

1. пройти по всем индексам массива
2. сравнивать значение по текущему индексу и по следующему (учесть, что следующего индекса может и не быть, если текущий - последний), т.е. сравнить соседние элементы
3. если значения не совпадают - добавлять первое значение в новый массив
4. если значения совпадают перепрыгивать через 1 элемент и делать 2)

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, что существуют более новые и короткие способы, но этот вариант, на мой взгляд, понятнее:

```js
let arr = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 32, 22, 22, 41, 50, 50];

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
    arr.splice(i - 1, 2);
    i -= 1;
  }
}

console.clear(); console.log('arr: ', arr);
```