# Как удалить из массива элементы, которые повторяются парно

Tags: javascript, массивы

Допустим есть массив

```
[3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Как удалить парные повторения, которые идут друг за другом и сделать на выходе массив

```
[3, 1, 5, 6, 0, 4, 5]
```

Comment: создать второй массив, в который складывать изменения. Дальше цикл по первому. Если текущее значение равно предыдущему - то `continue`, если нет, то сложить в массив аккумулятор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот так

```js
let skip = false;
let arr = [3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5];
let result = arr.reduce(
  (acc, item, index) => {
    if (!skip){
      if (item == arr[index + 1]) {
        skip = true; 
      } else {
        acc.push(item);
      }
    } else {
      skip = false;
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  
 console.log(result);
```

вот покороче

```js
let result = [3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 6, 6, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5].reduce((r,i,n,m) => {r.k||i===m[n + 1]?r.k=!r.k:r.s.push(i);return r;}, {s: [],k:false}).s;
  
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: Думаю, что код может быть чуть короче - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201717/265406

Comment: @UModeL да конечно. Я лишь указал чуть более понятный вариант

Comment: Добавил вариант короче. Но ясность это не добавило

Answer (score 1):

алгоритм:

1. идете в цикле по элементам массива
2. если элемент `arr[i]` равен элементу `arr[i+1]` или равен элементу `arr[i - 1]` ничего не делаете иначе добавляете элемент в новый массив
3. при 2) учесть граничные элементы и не выполнять одну или другую проверку в зависимости от того первый это или последний элемент массива